# Wrapper for Windows command line tool

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Using Windows 7, I want to write a wrapper for some command line tools to simplify their usage. Say I regularly use this executable with following options

```
someTool.exe -i infile -a option1 -b option2
```

I want to create a wrapper that executes the above command & options, and additionally accept more options (any number of options). So running this:

```
someToolWrapper.exe -c option3
```

would effectively run

```
someTool.exe -i infile -a option1 -b option2 -c option3
```

P.S. Preferably accomplish this with batch files or cygwin commands & be robust / versatile. I usually end up with brittle batch files that fail on edge cases.

Comment: I would do this using Powershell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SomeToolWrapper.bat:

```
someTool.exe -i infile -a option1 -b option2 -c %1
```

Run:

```
SomeToolWrapper.bat option3
```

Comment: `%*` instead of `%1` would make it generic (allows variable number of options)